# Compare a value from a CSV column in mysql with more checks

Tags: mysql, csv, sql-like

I need to have a query which has two parts.
I mean two where clause.

till now I have reached to the following, but it dosen't work properly.

```
SELECT * from items
where
      FIND_IN_SET( '3', category_id )
  AND postcode LIKE 'sw19%'
order by id
```

this query only runs the first part, i.e., the `FIND_IN_SET()` part. and just ignores the second part i.e., Postcode check...

I want to know is there a solution for this kind of query.

**DETAILS**

I want to compare the values from 2 columns:

- 1 column is a csv column , eg. 1,2,3,4,5
- the other is postcode B17 SW19 etc

Table is like the following.

```
---+------+-------------+----------+-
id | item | category_id | postcode |
---+------+-------------+----------+-
 1 | abc  | 1,2,3,4     | SW19     |
---+------+-------------+----------+-
 2 | def  | 3,4,5       | NW6      |
---+------+-------------+----------+-
 3 | xyz  | 6,7,8,9     | SW19     |
---+------+-------------+----------+-
 4 | ghi  | 8,9,10,11   | SW19     |
---+------+-------------+----------+-
```

etc.

if I want to select an entry whose `category_id` contains `'3'` AND whose postcode starts from `'SW'`, what query will it be?

Comment: But your existing SQL works fine (it doesn't return `id=2`, where `postcode='NW6'`)!  See [my sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/530df/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the solution which completely resolves my problem and though it would help someone in future.

Well, the query goes like this:

```
Select * from table_name where FIND_IN_SET('3', category_id) >0 AND postcode LIKE 'sw%'
```

Regards,
Shoaib.

Comment: How is that different to what you had in your question?

Comment: FIND_IN_SET('3', category_id) >0

Answer (score 0):

:) Just simple query for this

```
SELECT * FROM tablename1 WHERE category_id LIKE '%,3,%' AND postcode LIKE 'SW%'
```

Comment: Thanks @Shahid for answering but this query is giving funny results. if there are more entries, which dont have '3' in their csv column, and the postcode clause is removed or set to null/empty, it returns all the records, whether it has '3' in their csv column or not. Is their any solution for that?